# Why am i getting ERROR 1064 (42000) mysql error on procedure?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

What's wrong with my mysql 5.5 procedure?
I'm trying to create it via mysql client command terminal on linux.

```
    DELIMITER //
CREATE procedure merge()
BEGIN

  DECLARE old_outlet_id INT(10);
  DECLARE new_outlet_id INT(10);
  DECLARE gpid VARCHAR(255);
  DECLARE v_finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
  DEClARE cur CURSOR FOR select distinct google_place_id from service_providers_outlets group by google_place_id having count(google_place_id) > 1;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET v_finished = 1;

  OPEN cur;


getC: LOOP

 FETCH cur INTO gpid;

 IF v_finished = 1 THEN 
 LEAVE getC;
 END IF;

     SET old_outlet_id = (select id from service_providers_outlets o where google_place_id = gpid order by created_on limit 1);
     SET new_outlet_id = (select id from service_providers_outlets o where google_place_id = gpid order by created_on desc limit 1); 

     select concat('old_outlet_id', old_outlet_id);
     select concat('new_outlet_id', new_outlet_id);

     if old_outlet_id != new_outlet_id then
         update reviews_completed set outlet_id = new_outlet_id where outlet_id = old_outlet_id;
         update service_providers_offers_outlet_link set outlet_id = new_outlet_id where outlet_id = old_outlet_id;
         update service_providers_offers_redeemed set outlet_id = new_outlet_id where outlet_id = old_outlet_id;
         update reviews_questions_outlet_link set outlet_id = new_outlet_id where outlet_id = old_outlet_id;
         delete from dashboard_users_outlet_link where outlet_id = old_outlet_id;
         delete from service_providers_outlets where id = old_outlet_id;
     end if;

 END LOOP getC;

 CLOSE cur;

END //
DELIMITER ;
```

I'm getting the following error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'o where google_place_id = '' order by created_on
>   limit 1); ew_outlet_id = (selec' at line 22 mysql> DELIMITER ;

Answer (score 0):

Instead try using max and min

```
SET old_outlet_id = (select max(id) from service_providers_outlets o where google_place_id = '' );
SET new_outlet_id = (select min(id) from service_providers_outlets o where google_place_id = '');
```